# How can I upgrade a computer to 12.10 beta via Landscape?

Tags: upgrade, landscape

I have [Canonical Landscape](http://landscape.canonical.com) managing a couple of computers.

I want to upgrade one of them to Ubuntu 12.10 beta. I don't have access to the computer in question unfortunately (it's 400km away).

I know that you're not meant to upgrade the distro version without being prepared for a non-booting system etc, but I'd still like to know if it's possible to do with Landscape, and how.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, the Ubuntu Release upgrade feature of Landscape won't give you the option to upgrade to a beta release of Ubuntu.